# Unable to retrieve data for all pages using beautiful soup while writing to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm web scraping a particular website which scrapes different currency information. I'm unable to retrieve all data when i write to csv file. Please let me know ho to go about it

Code

```
   lista = ["eur-usd-historical-data","usd-jpy-historical-data",]
   listb=[]

   link = "https://www.investing.com/currencies/%d"
   for k,v in enumerate(lista):
       urlConcat=link.replace("%d",lista[k])
       k += 1
       listb.append(urlConcat)


   for url in listb:
       lista = []

       headers = {
       'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
        Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36',
       'accept': 
       'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',}
        response = requests.get(url,headers=headers).text
        data = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
        #print(data)
        divs = data.findAll("table", {"class": "genTbl closedTbl historicalTbl"})  
        for div in divs:
            row = ''
            row = div.findAll("td")
            for rows in row:
                if(rows.text.find("tr")):
                lista.append(rows.text)
        

        final_list = [lista[6*i:6*(i+1)] for i in range(int(round(len(lista)/6)) + 1)]

        final_df = pd.DataFrame(final_list,columns=['date','price','opne','high','low','% change'])
        final_df['currency'] = url
        final_df['currency'] = final_df['currency'].str.split('/').str[-1].str.split('-').str[:2].str.join('-')
         
        print(final_df)
        final_df.to_csv('result.csv')
```

**Here the result in CSV consists of data for only 1 currency. and if i print the final_df in a different cell it gives result only for one currency.
What should be done to fix this issue**

Answer (score 0):

Try appending to csv may be like:

```
final_df.to_csv('result.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```